# How to check if a value (in my checkbox) and has true? in a loop in JavaScript (not found on the forum)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I would like to make a loop to know if one of the answers to the checkbox is "true"

my code Html:

```
<ion-list>  
  <ion-item *ngFor="let modalite of current.modalites ; let i=index">
    <ion-label>{{modalite}} {{i}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="PFG" 
     [(ngModel)]="current.response[current.valModalites[i]]" checked="false">
    </ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

my code JS:

```
case "question_fermee_checkbox":
   console.log("checkbox");
   console.log(this.current.response,this.current.numero_question )
   while(verif < this.current.response.length){
      verif++
   } 
   retour= true;
  break;
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: where is your html code with the checkboxes?

Comment: Is this part of a switch statement?

Comment: yes in a switch but whether in a swtich or not it is not important

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop to set `verif = this.current.response.length` ? that's just what it does...

Comment: my code is wrong for that I ask for help because I want to loop to check the answers that there is one to True

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this, untested because I don't have your setup. I just filled in what is missing.

```
case "question_fermee_checkbox":
   console.log("checkbox");
   console.log(this.current.response,this.current.numero_question )
   retour = false;
   for(var verif = 0; verif < this.current.response.length; ++verif){
      var checkbox = this.current.response[verif];
      if(checkbox.checked) {
          retour= true;
          break;
      }
   } 

  break;
```

Comment: must loop through the responses (which I receive in this.current.response) and loop to check a "True"
when it is verified, it tells me true

Comment: I made the code so that it returns true when at least one box is checked. Using a loop,

Comment: no I do not want it to return true if a box is checked; I want him to loop the answers to check if there is a real one;
If a box is checked, it returns true
checked = true
unverified = "" or false
I have already done that I just want it to check that there is a TRUE thank you ! :)

Comment: I'm lost as to what you want. There is no HTML for `this.current.numero_question` in the view you showed. Maybe you can edit the question and explain better.

Comment: In fact my this.current.response (in ngModel) gives me the values: true or false or "nothing"
true = checkbox checked
that already does.

Comment: trés bien, je compris mieux l'anglais

Comment: Now, what I'm asking is how to make a loop that checks in "this.current.response". There is at least one true to move forward

Comment: help me please :(

Comment: I don't understand why my code doesn't do what you want. Try to understand my code so you can change it to what you need.